# How can I add a subdomain for a hostname in Active Directory DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, subdomain

We have an Active Directory DNS structure which maps hostnames to ip addresses, like such:

```
my-hostname.my-domain.my-tld
```

which resolves like this:

```
$ nslookup my-hostname.my-domain.my-tld                                                                                  
Server:     192.168.200.1
Address:    192.168.200.1#53

Name:   my-hostname.my-domain.my-tld
Address: 192.168.200.169
```

I would now like to use a "subdomain"/"virtualhost" for this hostname, such as

```
test.my-hostname.my-domain.my-tld
```

which I'd like to also resolve to the same ip address `192.168.200.169`. Is this even possbile? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. Delete the A record, so n funky stuff happens.
2. Create a new zone with the FQDN of the host.
3. create an empty A record under the new zone with the IP you want.
4. create a second CName record that returns the A record.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an A-record in DNS with the name "test.my-hostname.my-domain.my-tld" under the zone my-domain.my-tld - it will then create the needed zones for you (tested on a Server 2012 R2)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new domain under your AD DNS zone (named test or whatever you like) and create an A record in that zone for the host in question.